# nginx suddenly redirecting everything to 403 page, can this be debugged or traced?

Tags: nginx, selinux, http-status-code-403, centos6.6

I'm not sure what happened to my `nginx` install.  Suddenly all page requests are being redirected to the `403` page.

Yesterday I tried to add a user agent to block, restarted service from that point everything was being sent to 403.  I backed out that change, restart `nginx` and everything is still being directed to the `403` page.  Even if I remove the `$http_user_agent` and `$http_referer` if statements everything is still sent to 403.

I have even restored the entire `nginx` folder from a backup and all my page requests are continued to be directed to the 403 page....

Not sure how to troubleshoot this, the conf files come back clean.  Is there a trace I can do for `nginx` when requests come in?

```
[root@soupcan nginx]# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Here is the website conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/website1/access.log  main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/website1/error.log;

    root /srv/www/website1;

    ## Block http user agent - morpheus fucking scanner ##
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "morfeus fucking scanner|ZmEu|Morfeus strikes again.|OpenWebSpider v0.1.4 (http://www.openwebspider.org/)") {
        return 403;
     }

    if ($http_referer ~* (semalt.com|WeSEE)) {
        return 403;
    }

    ## Only allow GET and HEAD request methods. By default Nginx blocks
    ## all requests type other then GET and HEAD for static content.
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
      return 405;
    }


    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        ssi on;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/website1/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }


    # Redirect server error pages to the static page
    error_page 403 404 /error403.html;
    location = /error403.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript
        text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript
        image/svg+xml application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject;

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # Load virtual host configuration files.
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    # BLOCK SPAMMERS IP ADDRESSES
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/blockips.conf;
}
```

Permissions for webroot dir:

```
[root@soupcan nginx]# namei -om /srv/www/website1/
f: /srv/www/website1/
 dr-xr-xr-x root  root   /
 drwxr-xr-x root  root   srv
 drwxrwxr-x brian nobody www
 drwxr-x--x brian nobody website1
```

### **EDIT**

[Found out that CentOS 6.6 and SELinux breaks nginx.  Im still looking for a solution, but here is the cause.](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,254456,254456#msg-254456)

### **EDIT 2**

Solution posted below.

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: I'm getting `2015/01/22 10:13:25 [error] 10547#0: *2 "/srv/www/website1/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), ` Do I need to ensure the `nginx` user has access to `/srv/www/website1`?

Comment: Absolutely. Any files and/or directories that the nginx process need to access must have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Since root is running nginx.  If I run the  `namei -om /srv/www/website1/` I get the results posted in the OP....Is that right, Im not sure what would have changed to disallow it.

Comment: The worker processes should not be running as root. If you look at the nginx docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user the default is nobody.nobody.

Comment: I believe my worker is set to be user `nginx` based on the `nginx.conf`  The worker is user `nginx` as least that is what `htop` tells me

Comment: /website1/ must be readable for group or others !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by upgrading CentOS from 6.5 to 6.6 and how SElinux allows content type through.  With this upgrade SElinux by default only allows `httpd_t` content through (similar to how they treat apache), and because I store all my webcontent in `/srv/www/` these user created folders did not have content label set automatically by the system.

To check this run the following command against your webroot and your `/etc/nginx` directories and compare the content types:

```
ls -Z /srv/www/
```

I've run these commands and restarted `nginx` and everything is now working normally.

```
grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m nginx > nginx.te
grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nginx
semodule -i nginx.pp
```

Im not sure what this SElinux module does, but I found it reading [this post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=49280) about the same issue.  I may try backing it out today, because I think the second thing I did to fix this actually worked.

```
[09:15 AM] robotoverlord ~>chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /srv/www/
[09:15 AM] robotoverlord ~> ls -Z /srv/www/
drwxr-xr-x. www-data nobody unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 website1
[09:15 AM] robotoverlord ~>service nginx restart
```

[Additional info on content labeling for SElinix](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-02c04b0b030dd3c3d58bb7acbbcff033505dd3af)

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod ogw file
```

sets permission on file for **o**wner, **g**roup and **w**orld, each
being the sum of read(4), write(2), execute(1), if wanted

no proper access to read write

```
drwxr-x--x brian nobody website1
```

nginx is reading only, so you have to let him into!

```
cd /srv/
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Comment: Changed all permissions recursively for /website1/ to: drwxr-xr-x and it still sends me right to 403.  [Ive paired down the .conf file too to barebones](http://p.ngx.cc/3d) and still no luck.

Comment: [So it turns out CentOS 6.6 and SElinux breaks nginx](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,254456,254456#msg-254456) I dont have a fix yet, but at least a root cause.